# call function from asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Hello
AsyncTask is not a member of activity. in separate class. 
how can i call function of activity from AsyncTask ?
thanks

Comment: this is not enough info for understand your que. so plz explain your que with more detail..

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an instance of your activity in the constructor of your AsyncTask. But be sure to call the methods of activity only inside `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` methods, becuase they run on the UI Thread.

If you want to call some activity code while `doInBackground()`, then you should create a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and pass it to the `AsyncTask`, because you can not modify the ui from non UI thread.

Comment: i want to use it in onProgressUpdate()/ somekind of progress bar.

Comment: Then just pass an instance to your AsyncTask and call a method of it in onProgressUpdate().

Comment: Владимир, честно говоря я только знакомлюсь с ява и адроид, не подскажите где можно почитать про instance ? так понимаю это указатель на объект? можно пример как передать его в AsyncTask ?